# using dirPath Provider with WebDeploy

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy

I have a wcf application hosted in iis that i am trying to package using webdeploy. Everything works great with the visual studio tools, but i need to also create a logs folder and set permissions on it. For this i created a ProjectName.wpp.target file in my web project.
The file looks like this

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

<Target Name="CreateLogsDirectory" AfterTargets="AddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest">   
    <!-- This must be declared inside of a target because the property 
    $(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath) will not be defined at that time. -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="dirPath">
        <Path>$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)\logs</Path>
        <enableRule>DoNotDeleteRule</enableRule>
      </MsDeploySourceManifest>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="DeclareCustomParameters" AfterTargets="AddIisAndContentDeclareParametersItems">
    <!-- This must be declared inside of a target because the property 
    $(_EscapeRegEx_MSDeployDirPath) will not be defined at that time. -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="LogsDirectoryPath">
        <Kind>ProviderPath</Kind>
        <Scope>dirPath</Scope>
        <Match>^$(_EscapeRegEx_MSDeployDirPath)\\logs$</Match>
        <Value>$(_DestinationContentPath)/log</Value>
        <ExcludeFromSetParameter>True</ExcludeFromSetParameter>
      </MsDeployDeclareParameters>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

i can see that dirPath provider is added to the sourcemanifest file, but when i deploy the package it tries to create the source file path. Essentially the LogsDirectoryPAth item is not replacing the path. can someone point out what i need to do ? thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering your additional directory is inside your web application, it's not really necessary to include another `dirPath` provider and doing so would only lead to more headaches (additional parameter declarations, etc).

Here are some helpers I use to help with this kind of thing. Your application specific values can be declared in your `wpp.targets` file:

```
<!-- Items specific to your application (these should be in your wpp.targets) -->
<ItemGroup>
  <SkipDeleteFiles Include="logs" />

  <EmptyDirectoriesToDeploy Include="logs" />

  <AdditionalAcls Include="logs">
    <AclAccess>Write</AclAccess>
  </AdditionalAcls>
</ItemGroup>
```

And the following convention-based definitions can be either put in you `wpp.targets` or in a common targets file that can be imported into your `wpp.targets`:

```
<!-- 
  Empty directories
-->

<PropertyGroup>
  <BeforeAddContentPathToSourceManifest>
    $(BeforeAddContentPathToSourceManifest);
    CreateEmptyDirectories;
  </BeforeAddContentPathToSourceManifest>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="CreateEmptyDirectories">
  <MakeDir Directories="$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)\%(EmptyDirectoriesToDeploy.Identity)" 
           Condition="'@(EmptyDirectoriesToDeploy)' != ''" />
</Target>

<!-- 
  Additional ACLs 
-->

<ItemDefinitionGroup>
  <AdditionalAcls>
    <AclAccess>Write</AclAccess>
    <ResourceType>Directory</ResourceType>
  </AdditionalAcls>
</ItemDefinitionGroup>

<PropertyGroup>
  <AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>
    $(AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest);
    AddAdditionalAclsToSourceManifest;
  </AfterAddIisSettingAndFileContentsToSourceManifest>
  <AfterAddIisAndContentDeclareParametersItems>
    $(AfterAddIisAndContentDeclareParametersItems);
    AddAdditionalAclsDeclareParameterItems
  </AfterAddIisAndContentDeclareParametersItems>
</PropertyGroup>

<Target Name="AddAdditionalAclsToSourceManifest">
  <ItemGroup Condition="'@(AdditionalAcls)' != ''">
    <MsDeploySourceManifest Include="setAcl">
      <Path>$(_MSDeployDirPath_FullPath)\%(AdditionalAcls.Identity)</Path>
      <setAclResourceType Condition="'%(AdditionalAcls.ResourceType)' != ''">%(AdditionalAcls.ResourceType)</setAclResourceType>
      <setAclAccess>%(AdditionalAcls.AclAccess)</setAclAccess>
      <AdditionalProviderSettings>setAclResourceType;setAclAccess</AdditionalProviderSettings>
    </MsDeploySourceManifest>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<Target Name="AddAdditionalAclsDeclareParameterItems">
  <ItemGroup Condition="'@(AdditionalAcls)' != ''">
    <MsDeployDeclareParameters Include="Add %(AdditionalAcls.AclAccess) permission to %(AdditionalAcls.Identity) Folder">
      <Kind>ProviderPath</Kind>
      <Scope>setAcl</Scope>
      <Match>^$(_EscapeRegEx_MSDeployDirPath)\\@(AdditionalAcls)$</Match>
      <Description>Add %(AdditionalAcls.AclAccess) permission to %(AdditionalAcls.Identity) Folder</Description>
      <DefaultValue>{$(_MsDeployParameterNameForContentPath)}/@(AdditionalAcls)</DefaultValue>
      <DestinationContentPath>$(_DestinationContentPath)/@(AdditionalAcls)</DestinationContentPath>
      <Tags>Hidden</Tags>
      <ExcludeFromSetParameter>True</ExcludeFromSetParameter>
      <Priority>$(VsSetAclPriority)</Priority>
    </MsDeployDeclareParameters>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>

<!-- 
  Skip delete files and directories
-->

<PropertyGroup>
  <ImportPublishingParameterValuesDependsOn>
    $(ImportPublishingParameterValuesDependsOn);
    AddSkipDirectives;
  </ImportPublishingParameterValuesDependsOn>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <SkipDeleteItems Include="@(SkipDeleteFiles)" 
                   Condition="'@(SkipDeleteFiles)' != ''">
    <Provider>filePath</Provider>
  </SkipDeleteItems>

  <SkipDeleteItems Include="@(SkipDeleteDirectories)" 
                   Condition="'@(SkipDeleteDirectories)' != ''">
    <Provider>dirPath</Provider>
  </SkipDeleteItems>
</ItemGroup>

<!-- Uses MSBuild trickery to add an escaped version of the skip path to as 
     "EscapedPath" metadata -->
<Target Name="AddRegexEscapedPathMetadata" Outputs="%(SkipDeleteItems.EscapedPath)">
  <EscapeTextForRegularExpressions Text="%(SkipDeleteItems.Identity)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Result" 
            PropertyName="_Temp_EscapeRegEx_SkipDeleteItemPath" />
  </EscapeTextForRegularExpressions>

  <ItemGroup>
    <SkipDeleteItems Condition="'%(SkipDeleteItems.Identity)' == '%(Identity)'" >
      <EscapedPath>$(_Temp_EscapeRegEx_SkipDeleteItemPath)</EscapedPath>
    </SkipDeleteItems>
  </ItemGroup>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Clear value -->
    <_Temp_EscapeRegEx_SkipDeleteItemPath></_Temp_EscapeRegEx_SkipDeleteItemPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Target>

<Target Name="AddSkipDirectives" DependsOnTargets="AddRegexEscapedPathMetadata">

  <ItemGroup>
    <MsDeploySkipRules Include="%(SkipDeleteItems.Identity)">
      <SkipAction>Delete</SkipAction>
      <ObjectName>%(SkipDeleteItems.Provider)</ObjectName>
      <AbsolutePath>%(SkipDeleteItems.EscapedPath)</AbsolutePath>
    </MsDeploySkipRules>
  </ItemGroup>

</Target>
```

**NB** If you go to the extra effort to separate your packaging process from your deployment process, then technically your `SkipDeleteFiles` should be in your `pubxml` rather than your `wpp.targets`.

Comment: I'm very grateful for all the work that you do; most of my wpp knowledge comes from your posts. I found this post because I actually am trying to sync files using the dirPath which cannot live within the site root, but I'm having trouble figuring out how to express it in MSBuild. Hypothetically speaking, if OP's question wasn't better addressed with this answer, how could he have used dirPath? I hope to adapt the solution to address situations where the source and dest dirPath must differ to support build agent isolation (i.e. no shared absolute paths)

Comment: @bwerks - Glad to have been of assistance! If you ask this as a separate question, I'll take a look when I have the chance.

Comment: @RichardSzalay Thank you for the great job you have done with this research. Although it did not work for pathe with slash. So, I have to add the blank file to my directory and change the code a little bit: `<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Dir\SubDir\_blank.txt" />
    <SkipDeleteItems Include="Dir\SubDir">
      <Provider>filePath</Provider>
    </SkipDeleteItems>
    <EmptyDirectoriesToDeploy Include="Dir\SubDir" />
    <AdditionalAcls Include="Dir\SubDir" />
</ItemGroup>`